# Error in continuous_scale using R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am following an example in the book `Machine Learning for Hackers`. `R 2.15.1` and `ggplot 0.91` is used. I get the following error:

```
Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "date", identity, breaks = breaks,  : 
unused argument(s) (major = "5 years", format = "%Y")
In addition: Warning message:
In discrete_scale(aesthetic, "manual", pal, ...) :
"legend" argument in scale_XXX is deprecated. Use guide="none" for suppress the guide   display.
```

The code that I tried running is

```
state.plot<-ggplot(all.sightings, aes(x=YearMonth,y=Sightings))+ 
    geom_line(aes(color="darkblue"))+ 
    facet_wrap(~State,nrow=10,ncol=5)+
    theme_bw()+ 
    scale_color_manual(values=c("darkblue"="darkblue"),legend=FALSE)+   
    scale_x_date(major="5 years", format="%Y")+ 
    xlab("Time")+ylab("Number of Sightings")+
    opts(title="Number of UFO sightings by Month-Year and U.S. State (1990-2010)")
```

I used `library(scales)` but that did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: That book appears to have been published just prior to a fairly major release of **ggplot2** which changed quite a bit of the package. You might want to look at the [transition guide](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf).

Comment: (Specifically, there is no more `format` argument; you should be using `labels` now.)

Comment: So more specifically, I think that should be `scale_x_date(breaks="5 years", labels=date_format("%Y"))` (this is based on the examples in `?scale_x_date`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
state.plot<-ggplot(all.sightings, aes(x=YearMonth,y=Sightings))+ 
    geom_line(aes(color="darkblue"))+ 
    facet_wrap(~State,nrow=10,ncol=5)+
    theme_bw()+ 
    scale_color_manual(values=c("darkblue"="darkblue"),guide=FALSE)+   
    scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("5 years"), labels = date_format("%Y"))+ 
    xlab("Time")+ylab("Number of Sightings")+
    opts(title="Number of UFO sightings by Month-Year and U.S. State (1990-2010)")
```

Answer (score 1):

The new version of **ggplot** doesn't use "**opts**" any more, so we need to replace "**opts**" with "**labs**".

The right code for this is:

```
state.plot<-ggplot(all.sightings, aes(x=YearMonth,y=Sightings))+ 
    geom_line(aes(color="darkblue"))+ 
    facet_wrap(~State,nrow=10,ncol=5)+
    theme_bw()+ 
    scale_color_manual(values=c("darkblue"="darkblue"),guide=FALSE)+   
    scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("5 years"), labels = date_format("%Y"))+ 
    xlab("Time")+ylab("Number of Sightings")+
    labs(title="Number of UFO sightings by Month-Year and U.S. State (1990-2010)")
```